# How to save images using sqlite Database in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anyone please help me how to save the images using sqlite.

How to save and retrieve the images from sqlite DB?

Any samples please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?
Is it not just a case of writing the bytes (as an array) in to a blob field?